# Database interaction for technical and non-technical people

Tags: microsoft-excel, python, database

I have the following problem: I work in a team where a few team-members (inclduign myself) are programming savy (python) and like to use its power to couple information, do analyses and so on. While the programming savy part of the group might grow a little, not everyone will learn python and/or SQL.

Within this group there is data available in files that would benefit from being organized in a relational database such as pgsql. Organizing it in a relational database allows the programming savy people to benefit from a better structure, but it will also make it harder/impossible for the people used to excel to work with it.

I would like to create the situation where both programmers as well as non-programmers can work with the data, where programmers can use a direct connection to the data while non-programmers can still access and work with it in a easier way.

What options do I have?

Comment: Why would it make people that are used to excel unable to work with it (Data > External Data > Other Sources > SQL)? Are you certain the data is fit for a relational database? Who and how would you get the data into the database?

Answer (score 0):

*I would prefer to arrange a Customize tool or you can say ready to use Application Software for Non-programming group. Because neither they are confident enough nor eager to learn programming.*

The second thought, if possible try to maximise the scope of using Excel along side of Python for them and also arrange in house training to gear up with Python & SQL.

All depends how much space is available for Non-programming people in current circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution, which was implemented in my company, is to move the data to a relational database and provide a excel retrieval and update tool.  The end users of the excel tool get access to the data in excel yet the data is still in the more powerful layout.  Much of the difficulty is in ensuring the users of the excel tool can still make changes to the original data.